# Django: Initial Value for Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to show an initial value in the form. At runtime no errors occurs, the field stays empty. Why isn't it showing the value?

views.py:

```
def mieteinheit(request, wohnungsgruppenname):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #...
    else:
        form = WohnungseinheitenForm(request.POST or None,initial={'ort':'Hof'})
    template = loader.get_template('Immo/user/mieteinheit.html')
    context = {"wohnungsgruppenname":wohnungsgruppenname,"form": form}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))
```

.html-File:

```
<input class="form-control"  id="{{ form.ort.auto_id }}" name="ort" type="text" >
```

Form.py:

```
class WohnungseinheitenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ort = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In forms.py, add initial property to the ort field.

```
ort = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=100,initial='Hof')
```

Comment: Providing a brief explanation of your code would make this answer much stronger